I don't understand the use of the word "on"

West Broadway took him to the base of the World Trade Center and on into the lobby of one of the towers, where he made his thirteenth call of the day to Virginia Stillman.

The trilogy of New York
Paul Auster

It's not an article; it's an adverb indicating continuation of a movement or action. He went along West Broadway to the base of the WTC and then on  into the lobby of one of the towers. I went into my kitchen, walked to the back door and on into the garden. You can find this in any good dictionary.

I think nowadays you might find on called an intransitive preposition with the locative sense of "continuing forward".  But it was indeed called an adverb until lately.

Does this answer your question? Sat watching far on into the night

Colin Fine on the linked duplicate says On is not a preposition here, but an adverb, acting as an intensifier of "far". I'll buy that. But the label hardly matters. What's important is it's acting as an intensifier.

Compare I took my son to school and I took my son on to school. I think it's fair to say on "intensifies" took, which leads to the implication that I had already taken my son somewhere else before taking him [further] on to school.

@MichaelHarvey So can this sentence be changed to something like this: "West Broadway took him on to the base of the World Trade Center"?

Took him … on into the lobby means “not stopping before the lobby, but continuing at least into the lobby.” Compare to the use of on in

The speaker droned on for what seemed like years.

Merriam-Webster defines this adverbial sense of on as meaning
“in continuance or succession.”
